# Java ResultSet get nothing but sql get result in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am using MySql database which has one table 'tradeinfo'.
Table structure:

```
    Date          TradeCode 
    2017.01.01    0001
    2017.02.05    0002
    2017.03.05    0001
```

My sql to find lastest trading day of the one tradecode is

```
    SELECT TradeCode, MAX(date)  most_recent_time   FROM tradeinfo  WHERE  TradeCode = '0001'
```

I test the sql in Mysql db and can get right result which is "2017.03.05 0001"
But for my java code which is "lastestdbrecordsdate = rs.getDate("MOST_RECENT_TIME"); ", It ever return right result. But few days later, when run it again, I always get NULL.
My java code is:

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...",user,password);
    String sqlstatement = "SELECT TradeCode, MAX(date)  most_recent_time    FROM tradeinfo  WHERE  TradeCode = '0001'  ";
    PreparedStatement sqlstat = con.prepareStatement(sqlstatement);
    ResultSet rsquery = sqlstat.executeQuery(sqlstatement); 
    CachedRowSetImpl cachedRS = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    cachedRS.populate(rsquery);
    while(cachedRS.next() ) {
        System.out.println(cachedRS.getMetaData().getColumnCount());
        Date lastestdbrecordsdate = cachedRS.getDate("MOST_RECENT_TIME");
    }
```

Is the problem that I config the mysql wrongly or I write wrong java code?
Thanks all!

Comment: what is your returning result from SQL query on mysql?, because I think you select wrong column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here.  First, you should be using the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(date) most_recent_time FROM tradeinfo WHERE TradeCode = '0001'
```

Adding `TradeCode` to the select list doesn't make any sense because it is not an aggregate, but rather each record has a value for this column.

With regard to why you are getting null results, you need to call `ResultSet#next()` to advance the cursor to the first line:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...", user, password);
Statement sqlstat = con.prepareStatement(sqlstatement);
ResultSet rsquery = sqlstat.executeQuery();    // DON'T pass anything to executeQuery()
if (rsquery.next()) {
    Date lastestdbrecordsdate = rs.getDate("most_recent_time");
}
```

Another problem I just noticed is that you were passing in the query string to your call to `Statement#executeQuery()`.  This is wrong, and you should not be passing anything to this method.

Comment: Thank you . Sorry, I didn't upload my code correctly. I did use ResultSet#next(). But still get nothing. I have upload code again.

Comment: Your call to `executeQuery()` also was wrong.  Follow what my answer says and then comment again if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: After revise the code following your answer,it works. Thank you so much!